# Why isn't this in scope? Why is use strict blocking this?

Tags: arrays, perl, scope, strict

The language is Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
[...]
while ( my $res = $async->wait_for_next_response )
{
    [...]
    if ($res->is_success)
    {
        [...]
        my @relAuthorList = ($res->content =~ /<a +rel=\"author\" +href=\".*?\".*?>.*?<\/a>/gi);
        if (@relAuthorList)
        {
            if ($#relAuthorlList != 0) # Line 87
            {
                [...]
            }
            [...]
        }
        my @metaAuthorList = ($res->content =~ /<meta +name=\"author\" +content=\".*?\" *?>/gi);
        if (@metaAuthorList)
        {
            if ($#metaAuthorlList != 0) # Line 105
            {
                [...]
            }
            [...]
        }
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

When I run it, I get these errors:

```
$ ./findAuthorCanonical
Global symbol "@relAuthorlList" requires explicit package name at ./findAuthorCanonical line 87.
Global symbol "@metaAuthorlList" requires explicit package name at ./findAuthorCanonical line 105.
Execution of ./findAuthorCanonical aborted due to compilation errors.
$
```

I'm stumped. Strict is on. I'm using the `my` keyword to declare the array variables. I'm returning results from the `=~` operator as lists into arrays. I'm testing the arrays to make sure they have elements in them before I try to get the last index using the `$#array` as outlined in perldata.

When I turn strict off, it works as expected.

I've tried predeclaring them as arrays before I put any contents in them:

```
my @relAuthorList = [];
my @metaAuthorList = [];
```

That didn't work either.

Most of the answers around this involve scoping errors, but I can't see any I've made here. Some involve forgetting to declare a variable with `my` but I've done that. I've seen one that involves a type mismatch, trying to treat a scalar as an array. I couldn't find anything relevant to this.

So I ask: What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `[]` creates a reference to an empty array. `my @array;` is enough to initialize an array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic due to a simple typographical error.

Comment: Compare: `@relAuthorList` vs. `@relAuthorlList` and `@metaAuthorList` vs. `@metaAuthorlList` (extra "l"s after "Author").

Comment: :) Just **TRUST** to error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strict worked here. The declaration of the 2 arrays is spelled differently than their spelling in the lines 87 and 105.

Also, your checks for the arrays `!= 0` would allow an empty array (`== -1`). If you're checking for more than 1 element, the test would be `>=1` if I understand your intent here. Maybe you meant `@relAuthorList != 0` (which says count of items is 1 or more).

Comment: or just `if (@relAuthorList )`

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, I'm here for comic relief!

Comment: I say the camel case made it harder to spot this. Variable names are the only place where we don't like camels. That's why the Perl best practices suggest using snake case instead, which makes your var `@rel_author_list`, and your typo would have been `@rel_authorl_list`. That would have been way easier to spot.